# Show the real part of a complex function is a solution to the Airy Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am considering a function $v=$ Re$\left(e^{i(Nx + tN^3)} u\left(t,\frac{x + 3N^2t}{\sqrt{3N}}\right) \right)$, where $u$ is a smooth solution to the free Schrodinger equation, $i u_t = -u_{xx}$, and wish to show that this is an approximate solution of the Airy equation, in the sense that
$v_t + v_{xxx} = O(N^{
−3/2}).$

I have attempted to naively plug this function into the equation and differentiate, but this does not appear to work, and I am looking for hints as to how to proceed.

Comment: What does it mean to be an "approximate" solution?

Comment: The above edit provides what was given in the problem. How does one go about differentiating a function like v? Is this possible?